# networking - I can't open ports on Ubuntu 16.04 VPS

Tags: port-forwarding

I recently made a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS using [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/). I installed OpenVPN using [this script](https://github.com/Angristan/OpenVPN-install). But none of my ports are open. Only 22 is working. I want to open 1194 and 443 ports. 
Please, help!

```
root@SanFrancisco-VPN:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
2222                       ALLOW       Anywhere
4832                       ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
6000:6007/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere
6000:6007/udp              ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2222 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
4832 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
6000:6007/tcp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
6000:6007/udp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But NMAP gives following

```
root@SanFrancisco-VPN:~# nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-04 15:25 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000070s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.59 seconds

root@SanFrancisco-VPN:~# sudo netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1334/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1334/sshd
```

Comment: Digital Ocean has their own set of firewall controls from their user panel.  Go to the Digital Ocean management panel and adjust the firewall / security rules to permit those ports.

Comment: @ThomasWard I can't find any such settings within my DigitalOcean Panel

Comment: Your output from ufw does not show that 1194 or 443 is open. You must open them in ufw or any actions you take outside of the VM will do nothing.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I did that and sudo ufw status shows that all these ports are allowed but NMAP only shows 22.

Comment: I think you have to have a service listening on it for it to show up in NMAP.

Comment: I used http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check if port is open but no success. :(